# Which one is correct: “to have verbed” or “verbing”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, participles, gerund-vs-infinitive, ing, perfect-infinitive

I have two confusing sentences and I am in two minds whether the first or the second is more grammatically correct:

1. He was by far the most knowledgeable person **to have commented** on the subject, so it would have been foolish to disregard his opinions.
2. He was by far the most knowledgeable person **commenting** on the subject, so it would have been foolish to disregard his opinions.

Comment: They're both fine. So is ***to comment***, which more accurately reflects the tense of #2. But I think there's something not quite right about the usage of ***since*** here - you should probably be using ***so, thus, hence***.

Comment: This is a property of the superlative construction (try it without _the most knowledgeable_). Superlatives are accompanied by propositions about the set being awarded a maximum member, which are sometimes stated as clauses, or as infinitives or gerunds, or as prepositional phrases, or just understood in context. There are a lot of choices available.

Answer (score -2):

The meanings are different:

1. **His commenting** had been **completed before** the "was," reflecting the main time instant in the past that is considered.
2. **His commenting** was still taking place **at that very time, in parallel.**

And:

since --> thus

Comment: No, the gerund can mean it's still going on, but as a rule it doesn't have to. _When the school board took up the proposal last night, she turned out to be the most persuasive person commenting._

Comment: @JohnLawler But wasn't her "commenting" still going on at the time the proposal was taken up during the discussions __last night__? At least for part of the time?

Comment: But it isn't going on at the time of reporting, and all it means is that she is one of the people who commented at the meeting. It's just a gerund; it's not the progressive construction. They're completely different, as different as infinitive _to go_ and present tense _we go_, but they use the same verb form, same as infinitive and present tense do.